# Gmail: how to find all emails sent to somebody (to:) who is not in cc or bcc?

Tags: email, gmail

In Gmail, I want to find all emails that I sent "to:" somebody. But I don't want to see the emails sent this person in cc: or bcc:.

When I type "to:xxx@yyy.com", Gmail returns all emails sent to this person either in "to:" or "cc:" or "bcc:". This is not what I want. I want to see only the emails sent in to:.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not possible to do so as Gmail doesn't give us an exclusion field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the following condition to filter your results

```
to:xxx@yyy.com -(bcc:xxx@yyy.com | cc:xxx@yyy.com)
```

You can read more about the: **[Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190/)**

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thanks. it works!