# Filter BCC on Gmail for forwarded email

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have an email support@mybrand.com that forwards messages to mycompanysupport@gmail.com.

Some customers send emails and put support@mybrand.com in bcc.

How can I retrieve thoses emails with a Gmail filter ?

I tried the following searches :

```
bcc: support@mybrand.com
deliveredto:support@mybrand.com
delivered-to:support@mybrand.com
```

None of them seem to work.

Anyone has an idea on how to make this filter ?

Comment: I know you mention you already tried to and didn't work (though it should). Maybe a combination (or similar) as in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138832/117311) can help.

Comment: Have you tried `bcc:xxx@yyy.com -(to:xxx@yyy.com | cc:xxx@yyy.com)` ?